# Batch readability without compromising execution with variables

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

I'm currently writing a performance assistant in batch, written so everyday people can read, and edit it. My question is, is it possible to optimize batch code without compromising it's readability? 
Here's a little snippet of what I have:

```
    for /f "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do set VERSION=%%i.%%j
    if "%version%" == "10.0" SET WinX10=1
    if "%version%" == "6.3" SET WinX81=1
    if "%version%" == "6.2" SET WinX80=1
    if "%version%" == "6.1" SET WinX7=1
    if "%version%" == "6.0" SET WinXVista=1
    if "%version%" == "5.2" SET WinXXP64=1
    if "%version%" == "5.1" SET WinXXP32=1
    goto OSScanFinder
    rem Scans your OS for version specific files, required for Extreme, Gaming, and Boot
    :OSScanFinder
    if defined WinX10 goto BootCleanWindows10Latest
    if defined WinX81 goto BootCleanWindows81
    if defined WinX80 goto BootCleanWindows80
    if defined WinX7 goto BootCleanWindowsSeven
    if defined WinXVista goto BootCleanVista
    if defined WinXXP64 goto BootCleanXP64
    if defined WinXXP32 goto BootCleanXP32
    @echo Couldn't find your Operating System.
    @echo I don't support Win2000, Windows Server 2003/R2/2008/R2/2012/R2
    @echo Try running as administrator. If that doesn't work, please contact me at the address provided inside of the .bat file.
    pause
    exit
```

And

```
rem Chrome
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe" SET ChromeYes=Defined
rem uTorrent
if exist "%userprofile%\Downloads\utorrent.exe" SET uTorrentYes=Defined

if defined ChromeYes TASKKILL /im Chrome.exe /f
if defined uTorrentYes TASKKILL /im utorrent.exe /f
```

I'm not asking for someone to optimize my code, just if anything could be written better, or if there is a better alternative to using "IF DEFINED" and "SET " while maintaining readability.

Comment: FWIW, The best way to get readable code is to use a more modern language (PowerShell, VBS, bash, C#).  Batch and readability really don't go well together.  All else being equal, your code is pretty clear.

Comment: This post might be better suited on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), supposing the script is working...

Comment: It does work (There's a lot more than just the snippets), but it's not ready for full scale review yet. I will most likely post it there once it's finished, but I'm still adding a lot to the script, and working with 7 different OS's takes some time.

Comment: Old post, by I'd still like to comment on what @RyanBemrose wrote: I don't think he's wrong, batch is not really supposed to be a language to rely on too much. Still, often times I find myself doing some quick tasks directly from Windows's terminal, and it escalates a little bit, so I switch to a batch file to debug what otherwise would be a one-liner. In this scenario, getting some readability to a .cmd file can be helpful. I also have a second point: I didn't ever try to do it differently, but in my experience, batch files go great with unattended Windows installations!

Comment: (Oh, and PowerShell is better, of course, but I don't really use it at all, and even if I've been told it's not that difficult to learn, that *is* an extra-effort. On the other hand, one-liners escalating to batch file are — or at least were for me — a very natural path to actually start using a real language!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *readability* is an abstract concept, and hence matter of personal preference. For example, *in my opinion*, in your code you do the same question two times in different ways, so it is unnecessarily complex. You could do something like this:

```
for /f "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do set VERSION=%%i.%%j
if "%version%" == "10.0" goto BootCleanWindows10Latest
if "%version%" == "6.3"  goto BootCleanWindows81
if "%version%" == "6.2"  goto BootCleanWindows80
if "%version%" == "6.1"  goto BootCleanWindowsSeven
if "%version%" == "6.0"  goto BootCleanVista
if "%version%" == "5.2"  goto BootCleanXP64
if "%version%" == "5.1"  goto BootCleanXP32

@echo Couldn't find your Operating System.
@echo I don't support Win2000, Windows Server 2003/R2/2008/R2/2012/R2
@echo Try running as administrator. If that doesn't work, please contact me at the address provided inside of the .bat file.
pause
exit
```

However, *in my opinion* a shorter code is always easier to read and understand, so it is more *readable*. I would write this code this way:

```
for /f "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do set VERSION=%%i.%%j
call Version-%version%
if errorlevel 1 (
   @echo Couldn't find your Operating System.
   @echo I don't support Win2000, Windows Server 2003/R2/2008/R2/2012/R2
   @echo Try running as administrator. If that doesn't work, please contact me at the address provided inside of the .bat file.
)
pause
exit
```

... and add documentation into each one of the code segments:

```
:Version-10.0  WinX10  BootCleanWindows10Latest
rem Apropriate code here
exit /B

:Version-6.3  WinX81  BootCleanWindows81
rem Apropriate code here
exit /B

... etc, until

:Version-5.1  WinXXP32  BootCleanXP32
rem Apropriate code here
exit /B
```

Comment: Interesting changes. And yes, I know what I am asking for is subject to personal taste, and the documentation piece you added is quite helpful, but my objective is for someone who's never opened a batch file, be able to read and edit it. Going to mark your answer as the best, as you provided all the information I could ask for. Thanks.

Comment: +1, You pretty much mirrored my thoughts. You should probably mention that each version subroutine must `EXIT /B  0 `, else your CALL error check will write out misleading information if the subroutine encountered an error.